# Is there a way to use a different module for admin in the same application?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I'm setting up a new Angular7 application and I want that the root url point to one module and the /admin point to another one.

`const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent,
        loadChildren: '../registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AppComponent,
        loadChildren: '../admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
    }
];`

What I want to achieve is that the Registration module should be loaded when www.xy.com called and the admin module is loaded when www.xy.com/admin is called.

Right now the registration module is loaded for each endpoint.

You guys have any idea how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're lazy loading a module, there is no need for the `component attribute` on the root routing.  The lazy loaded modules will contain their own set of child routes which will determine which component to display.  You're routing would look like this.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
    }
];
```

---

I also put together a stackblitz of a working example of how you might structure something like this.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zq2cmy
>
> https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. It seems that I forgot to add the routing module to my admin module and that caused the issue.